# New field added in CrystalReport template it is not showed

Tags: crystal-reports

I have the following problem. I need to update an existing CrystalReport template with a new field that was previous added to the view from where the report is retrieving the data.

First step that I did, it was to update the database, by going to the database menu option -> verify database and the view was updated.

Second step was to create the new section and then I have added text, bars, etc, and the new field. I checked if the field is retrieving data by using the option *Browse Data*

Unfortunately, I am not able to use the *Preview option* because the report needs some specific parameters and without those it is trying to load all the data and crystalreport editor is crashing when doing this. I also tried the options *Preview Samples* but it is only allowing me to preview *First X* records and we have a very large amount of records.

My issue is that after the template is updated on the server, the new field it is not retrieved(even if the sql that runs in the background it is retrieving the correct data).

This is how the field it is added in the template:
[image: Crystal report template]

And this is how it looks after is generated:
[image: Crystal report that was generated]

Thanks

Comment: When the dataset is too large to preview, I recommend adding some code to the report's selection criteria using the Select Expert, then you remove the code when you are done testing.  This allows you to control the sample size of data used in testing.

Comment: @R.McMillan thank you for your suggestion, I will try to implement that. But do you have any idea related to the problem that I have encountered?

Comment: If you right click on the new database field in the Field Explorer of your Crystal Reports designer and then click "Browse Data...", does it show you a list of the different values the field contains?  If it doesn't, then there may be an issue with the database view you are using as a datasource.  Its hard to say much regarding this issue without some more specific details about the datasource, the database connection type, and the report's design.

Comment: I have managed to fix the issue. It was related to a SQL query that it was used in addition to the report itself